# Parameters of Contract

Tags: solidity, javascript

Quick introduction:I send arrays of strings from a python script to a js script.
The data sent are of these type:
[image]
and are stored in a var "data".So I have this object("data") which contains 12 "blocks",evry of which contains ID_utent=...Xacc=..Yacc=...Zacc=..Date=..Time=..(as shown in the image)
(here there is the JS code if you want to see:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 10001;


net.createServer(function(sock) {


console.log('__________');


sock.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATI:\r' + data);


});


sock.on('close', function(data) {
    console.log('__________');
});

}).listen(PORT, HOST);

console.log('Server listening on ' + HOST +':'+ PORT);
```

I want these data saved on blockchain.
I thought to use a smart contract like this

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

So my question is: Could I save these data passing directly "data" as an object parameter?? like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract SimpleStorage {
    object storedData;

    function set(object x) {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() constant returns (object) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Solidity is a strongly typed language and will not accept arbitrary data. You can try saving byte arrays

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Struct type in solidity, you can use it to model your data, but the only challenge is, you can not return a struct in solidity yet.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract ItemListContract {
struct item {
    bytes iname;
    uint16 itemid;
    bytes icode;
    uint ivalue;
}

uint itemCount;
mapping(bytes => item) itemList;
item[] itemArray;

function ItemListContract() {
    log0('hi');
}

function addItem(bytes name, uint16 iid, bytes code, uint val) {        
    var itemnew = item(name, iid ,code, val);
    // log0(itemnew);
    itemList[code] = itemnew;
    itemArray.push(itemnew);
    itemCount++;
}

function countItemList() constant returns (uint count) {     
    return itemCount;
}

function removeItem(bytes code) {
    delete itemList[code];
    itemCount--;
}

function getItem(bytes code) constant returns (bytes iname, uint val) {   
    return (itemList[code].iname, itemList[code].ivalue);
}
}
```

in the sample code above, the struct will be the format for your data

Comment: A code example would improve this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
  contract SimpleStorage {
    struct Obj{
        int info;
        uint[2] exDataArr;
        bytes32[2] exDataStr;
    }
    mapping(int =>Obj) Obj;
    function set(uint x,uint[2] exDataArr,bytes32[2] exDataStr) {
        Obj[x]= Obj({info:info,exDataArr:exDataArr,exDataStr:exDataStr});
    }
```

function get(int x) public constant returns(int,uint[2],bytes32[2]){
    uint[3] memory exDataInt = Obj].exDataArr;
    bytes32[3] memory exDataStr = Obj[x].exDataStr;
    return (Obj[x].info,exDataInt,exDataStr);
}

}
//maybe this can help you~~~~

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!  Please see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer